# way to convert a decimal formatted value to the original value

Tags: java, decimalformat

Initially I may have a double, float or similar type value.
I'm using DecimalFormat to format this values as "##,###.000".
That formatted value, which is now a String I want to return back to it's original value of a primitive type.

Currently, I'm solving parsing issue by replacing comma with empty character. `doubleToString.replace(",", "")`

However, later I may change the formatPattern and replace it with dot instead of comma "##.###.00" or perhaps specify a different format.

My question is, as title says, is there a way to parse this value back to the original value (initial type and value), or I have to manually handle this by replacing etc.?

My code example:

```
double initialValue = 12345;
System.out.println("Initial value: " + initialValue);

final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("##,###.000");

// double to string
final String doubleToString = decimalFormat.format(initialValue);
System.out.println("Double to String: " + doubleToString);

// string to double
final double stringToDouble = Double.parseDouble(doubleToString.replace(",", ""));
System.out.println("String to Double: " + stringToDouble);
```

Comment: Parse it with the same formatter.

Comment: Why not just retain the original value?  For example, in the code you're showing, you can still access the `initialValue` variable and output that.

Comment: There exist double values where this transform is not reversible. You need to consider how you want to handle those corner cases.

Comment: Cool, basically this solved `decimalFormat.parse(doubleToString);`

Comment: Since you are formatting with only three decimal, you will in most cases lose precision in formatting, and there’s no way to get that precision back in parsing. I thought it worth mentioning, but it could easily be OK for your use case, you decide.

Comment: Why not just keep the number as a `double` to begin with, and then use the `DecimalFormat` when you want to display it, giving whatever correct-at-the-time format is required?